# How can I extract images from a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, images

I have a pdf file that consists of an image per page.

Are there any command line programs that can extract these images?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf

Answer (score 4):

If it's just image per page, you can just rasterize the pdf, for instance, with imagemagicks' `convert -density 300 test.pdf test.png` where 300 is in dpi.

However, this doesn't get the original raw image out, for that, you need something else - waiting for a better answer.